# JTable sorting and Jasper report output

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jasper-reports

In my one of Java swing desktop based applications, I am using a `JTable` and I added the sorting functionality for a column. I need to sort it according to the number values added by the user and then get the jasper report output.

Currently after the sorting and print the report, the report is not showing the sorted order. But the order when the values taken from the DB. How can I print the report which the user's table sorting order?

This is my jasper report generating code

```
try {
    DefaultTableModel de = (DefaultTableModel)Dashboard.catalogTbl.getModel();
    JRTableModelDataSource jr = new JRTableModelDataSource(de);
    String reportName = reportPath + "reports/AuctionSale/Catalogue/catalouge_frm_tbl.jrxml";
    String compiledName = reportPath + "reports/AuctionSale/Catalogue/catalouge_frm_tbl.jasper";
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("Lot_No", "Lot No");
    params.put("Mark", "Mark");
    params.put("Invoice", "Invoice");
    params.put("Grade", "Grade");
    params.put("Weight", "Weight");
    params.put("Price", "Price");
    params.put("Buyer", "Buyer");
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(reportName, compiledName);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledName, params, jr);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You might want to look more closely at the tag selections in future.  I bet that [tag:jasper] is not what you thought it was.  ;)  BTW [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Mujahid what's, where's your problem exactly, because JasperReports and Java API are by different vendors,

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added the report generating code here. Please can you check it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the report is generated based on the `TableModel`, while typical sorting only affect the `JTable` itself, not the model.

What you could do is decorate the table model which you pass to your report generator so that it takes over the ordering of your `JTable`. Something in the style of

```
public class TableModelDecorator implements TableModel{
  private TableModel delegate;
  private JTable table;

  @Override
  public Object getValueAt( int rowIndex, int columnIndex ) {
    return delegate.getValueAt( table.convertRowIndexToView( rowIndex ), table.convertColumnIndexToView( columnIndex ) );
  }
}
```

but then for all relevant methods.

Comment: Guesses and suggestions to provide more information are moving close to 'comment' territory.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: I am  quite new here. Are there any guidelines when to use comments and when to use actual answers ? I did not encounter such section in the FAQ

Comment: I'm not sure of any references for you, just past experience.  I'm also not *sure* whether it should be an answer or comment.  From my experience, it seems border-line either way.

Comment: Hi Robin,

Please check the question again. I added the code tht I used to generate the report

Thanks

Comment: Like I thought, you just pass the table model, which is unaware of any sorting that is applied

Comment: @Robin Yes, can you please let me know how can I make it affect to the table model. Thanks

Comment: +1 for the correct idea - just translated to jasper speak :-)

Answer (score 2):

@Robin answer is basically correct, just translating to jasper speak :-)

The "decorator" is a custom implementation of JRDataSource or (here) JRRewindableDataSource. Make it data-only and base on the table's RowSorter, something like (beware: just compiled, not tested!)

```
public class JRTableSorterDataSource implements JRRewindableDataSource {

    private RowSorter<? extends TableModel> sorter;

    private int currentRow = -1;

    private HashMap<String, Integer> columnNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public JRTableSorterDataSource(RowSorter<? extends TableModel> sorter) {
        if (sorter == null) return; // do nothing, no sorter
        this.sorter = sorter;
        TableModel tableModel = sorter.getModel();
        if (tableModel != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                this.columnNames.put(tableModel.getColumnName(i),
                        Integer.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        Integer columnIndex = this.columnNames.get(fieldName);
        return sorter.getModel().getValueAt(sorter.convertRowIndexToModel(currentRow), columnIndex.intValue());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        if (sorter == null || sorter.getModel() == null)
            return false;
        this.currentRow++;
        return (this.currentRow < sorter.getViewRowCount());
    }

    @Override
    public void moveFirst() throws JRException {
        this.currentRow = -1;
    }

    protected int getColumnIndex(JRField field) throws JRException {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        Integer columnIndex = this.columnNames.get(fieldName);

        if (columnIndex != null) {
            return columnIndex;
        } else if (fieldName.startsWith("COLUMN_")) {
            return Integer.parseInt(fieldName.substring(7));
        }
        throw new JRException("Unknown column name : " + fieldName);
    }

}
```

Then use it when setting up your report:

```
JRDataSource jr = new JRTableSorterDataSource(Dashboard.catalogTbl.getRowSorter());
/// ... same as your example
```

**Edit**

just a very quick runnable snippet (too lazy to do a full report, forgot how those files work ;-) - so here we create a table (with a standard SwingX model), create a dataSource on its RowSorter and loop over the values of the first column, no problem:

```
    JTable table = new JXTable(new AncientSwingTeam());
    JRDataSource source = new JRTableSorterDataSource(table.getRowSorter());
    table.getRowSorter().toggleSortOrder(0);
    JRField field = createField("First Name");
    String firstNames = "First Name: ";
    while (source.next()) {
        firstNames += "\n  " + source.getFieldValue(field);
    }
    LOG.info(firstNames);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I run that code and I'm getting that following exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at action.JRTableSorterDataSource.getFieldValue(JRTableSorterDataSource.java:43)
 `

Comment: Thanks. I don't speak Jasper, only Java and a bit of Swing ;-)

Comment: @Mujahid well, as I said, didn't run - probably missed a guard against null somewhere. And as you know, this forum is about helping, not about doing all the work - simply track it down :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Something late, but I hope it helps someone:

In this code, what I do is that after applying the filters in the jTable1, place the rows  obtained in the auxiliary model.

Then I assigned the auxiliary model to the auxiliary table. And that table is the one I'll send to JasperReports.

```
//** jTable1 is the table in the jFrame where the data is loaded and I apply
//the RowFilter or RowSorter filters

    DefaultTableModel dataModel_tableFiltered = null; //auxiliary model
    JTable tableAuxiliary = null; //table where we will put the auxiliary model

    public constructor {
            
        dataModel_tableFiltered = new DefaultTableModel ();
        // Set the number and name of the columns in the auxiliary model
        for (int i = 0; i <jTable1.getColumnCount(); i ++) {
            dataModel_tableFiltered.addColumn(jTable1.getColumnName (i));
        }
        
        tableAuxiliary = new JTable ();
    }



    private void btn_PrintActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        fillModel_filtered ();

        try {
            Map params = new HashMap ();
            params.put ("nameCustomer", "**");

            JRDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource (tableAuxiliary.getModel ());
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport (reportPath, params, dataSource);
            JasperViewer.viewReport (print, false); // true == Exit on Close
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }

     }

    // Put resulting rows in the model after applying filters in jTable1
    public void fillModel_filtered () {
        dataModel_tableFiltered.setRowCount (0); // Empty rows of the model

        for (int i = 0; i <jTable1.getRowCount (); i ++) {
            Object row [] = new Object [jTable1.getColumnCount ()];
            for (int j = 0; j <jTable1.getColumnCount (); j ++) {
                row [j] = jTable1.getValueAt (i, j);
            }
            dataModel_tableFiltered.addRow (row);
        }
        tableAuxiliary.setModel(dataModel_tableFiltered); // Very Important
    }
```